# Ajax getting JSOn data doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am trying to call an MVC method via Ajax. The code on client is as follow:

```
 var serviceUrl = "/Regions/GetRegionPoints";

$.get(serviceUrl, { id:region_id}, function (data) { alert("Data Loaded: " + data); });
```

and my MVC method is:

```
   public JsonResult GetRegionPoints(string id)
    {
        var model = GetRegionPoints();
        if (model.Any())
        {
            return new JsonResult(){Data = model};
        }
        return new JsonResult();
    }
```

I can see that the client calls Ajax and then my action is called, but there is no success and there is no data on client ( alert("data loaded") ) is not called.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because you're using GET method and if so you've to return result like this (if of course the javascript is correct and the method is fired)

```
return new JsonResult()
{                
     // Some Data
     JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
};
```